# Gradient of $\log_2\operatorname{Tr}(AX)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, trace

Consider complex-valued matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ with proper size, such that the matrix product $\mathbf{AX}$ is defined. (In case it is needed in this question, $\mathbf{X}$ is a positive semi-definite (PSD) Hermitian matrix defined as $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{T}$; this info might, however, not be useful in this particular question - this is not a homework assignment or anything like that.)

I am interested in calculating:
$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \log_{2}\left(\operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{AX}\right)\right)$$
I (think that I) know the following:
$$\nabla_{\mathbf{X}} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{AX}\right) = \mathbf{A}^{T}$$
I also know that if $x$ is a scalar, then
$$\log_{2}(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}$$
which might be useful in case I have to utilize the natural logarithm instead of the base-2 one.

But I don't know how to compute the gradient in question. Any description of the steps taken/the procedure required for such a computation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: How are you defining $\log_2$ of complex values? $\ln(x)$ is not a single-valued function on the complex numbers.

Comment: That said, you should get in general, if $f:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^+,$ then $$\nabla \ln f=\frac{1}f\nabla f.$$ This should work for complex, too, as long as you exclude cases where $f$ is on the "cut" of $\ln.$ And $\log_2$ is, as you've noted, just a constant times $\ln.$

Comment: So, if you are correct about the trace, you should get: $\frac{\log_2 e}{\operatorname{Tr}(AX)}A^T.$

Comment: Yes, perhaps I should have mentioned that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{a}\mathbf{a}^{H}$, where $\mathbf{a}$ is a Circulalry Symmetric Complex Gaussian (CSCG) vector; its complex-valued elements are i.i.d. random variables distributed according to $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$. Also, as stated above, $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{H}\succeq\mathbf{0}$. The trace $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{AX})$, as far as I understand, is a real number; thus, it can serve as the argument of the $\log(\cdot)$ function.

Comment: Ok, thank you @ThomasAndrews .

Comment: With $X$ and $A$ as you define in the comments then $\mathrm{Tr}[AX] = a^H X a \geq 0$ as $X \geq 0$. So you don't have any issues with complex logarithms. Or equivalently $\mathrm{Tr}[AX] = x^H A x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is hermitian, then $A^H=A\:$ and $\:A^T=A^*$

If $X$ is likewise hermitian, then the indicated trace function
is $\sf Real$ and can be differentiated (in the Wirtinger sense)
as follows
$$\eqalign{
\def\f{{\large\tau}}
\def\p{\partial}
\f\; &= {\rm Tr}(AX) \:=\: A^T:X \\
d\f\, &= A^T:dX \\
\frac{\p\f}{\p X} &= A^T = A^* \\
}$$
where a colon has been used to denote the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
B:C &= \sum_j\sum_k B_{jk}C_{jk}
   \;=\; {\rm Tr}\!\left(B^TC\right) \\
}$$
The last task is logarithmic differentiation
$$\eqalign{
\def\e{\log_2(e)}
\def\l{\lambda}
\l &= \log_2(\f)  \:=\: \e\cdot\log(\f) \\
\frac{\p\l}{\p X} &= \frac{\e}{\f}\left(\frac{\p\f}{\p X}\right) 
\:=\: \frac{A^T\e}{{\rm Tr}(AX)} \\
}$$